# Export-SPWeb invalidData

Tags: export

I have a SharePoint site collection at https://myurl.com/bi and under that a site called help. I’m trying to export a single list (a task list called testtasks) out of there through PowerShell using the following command:

```
Export-SPWeb –Identity https://myurl.com/bi -path “c:\export\export.cmp” –itemurl “/bi/help/lists/testtasks” –verbose
```

However, this just fails with the following:

```
Export-SPWeb: At line:1 char:1
CategoryInfo: InvalidData
FullyQualifiedError: Microsoft.Sharepoint.PowerSHell.SPCmdLetExportWeb
```

I’m guessing this is some sort of syntax error and reading around it seems to be the –ItemUrl param that’s problematic. However, I’ve tried lots of combinations, including

```
–itemurl “/bi/help/lists/testtasks”
–itemurl “/help/lists/testtasks”
–itemurl “help/lists/testtasks”
–itemurl “bi/help/lists/testtasks”
–itemurl https://myurl.com/bi/help/lists/testtasks
```

But get the same error (or an error telling me its an invalid URL.

I've previously run Add-SPShellAdmin for my user and also given myself db_owner permissions on the DB.

Can anyone fathom what I’m doing wrong here or if I’ve missed something?

Thanks

Comment: Can You try to do it with HTTP, not with HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduced. In my case works this code

```
Export-SPWeb "http://localhost/sites/bi/help/" -path "c:\export\export.cmp" –itemurl "Lists/testtasks"  –verbose
```

Comment: Thank you. This syntax did indeed work. Seems the online documentation is so inconsistent :(